# Will increasing the camera's focal length decrease the render image quality?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

i know it is keyframable, and its perfect to zoom in. And ive tried testing it with two pictures, one with 50mm focal length and the other is 100mm focal length.
after i got the result, i zoom in the 50mm and compare both picture.
it seems like both image is the same, meaning using the focal length deteriorate the image quality. or maybe i render both of them with just 10 sample on both picture.
Anyway i wasn't sure if i'm right, that's why i'm here. Can you guys confirm my test?

50mm focal
[image]

50mm focal zoom
[image]

100mm focal
[image]

Comment: It should not be true. .. Caan you show us your tests?

Comment: If all you change is focal length, then the 100 mm version will have double the pixels for the same length = quadruple the pixels for the same area. However, if you render the 100 mm version in 50% resolution, the two renders should be *roughly* the same: https://i.imgur.com/07ha8OC.gif . For low samples amount making any change affecting the sample seed might make either version better just by chance. There also might be effects that don't exactly scale with 50% resolution, but I can't think of an example…

Comment: i'll upload the pictures
so im wrong then? i was hoping i was wrong, I mean to be fair, i did render it with 10 samples